# schedule sql job triggered by data load

Tags: sql-server-2005, jobs

I have an Sql Server 2005 database where some data will be refreshed daily from outside systems (Oracle). Specifically several tables will be loaded daily, and I need to schedule a job to start only after the last table is refreshed. How can I do this? Should I use a table that will store specific info about data load and to read from that regularly, as a first step in sql job? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have the last thing the external database does is update current run.  When  your job complets have it set last run = current run.  when your job starts (have it check the status if the two aren't different try agian over X periods; then fail, if different, then your job runs.

Comment: what do you mean "external database does is update current run" - should I ask them to write something somewhere or this is a property of an sql object?

Comment: You need someone way for them to notify you that the job is done.  I was suggesting since they are already updating the several tables; have them insert/update a field/column in a table of your choosing to indicate job completion;  alternatively they must have record of the job completion somewhere; and you could reach into that system and grab that indicator.  No this isn't a property.

Comment: yes, I think the job completion insertion is the most simple and efficient way to check the external job status - thanks

Comment: @DanielIvanov, if xQbert's answer is appropriate, please consider voting up or marking as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need mechanism to know that external system finished updating your data.

Guess it is some table (SYNC_TBL for instance) in SQL Server that external system inserts to or updates some record to notify end of update by external system.

If You need to:

- start your job as soon as updating is finished - put trigger on SYNC_TBL table and execute job using [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx).
- start your job some time after updating is finished - schedule job to run every 15 minutes and check SYNC_TBL in the first step to see whether your job should proceed or not

Note that You need to have another check on external system side: updating data probably should not start again until job finishes its execution. You can use column Processed BIT in SYNC_TBL to mark whether data is processed by your job or not.

Comment: there is no need to start the job right in the moment the update is finished it is ok after several minutes - although, because job runtime will not be longer than 5-6 hours, there will not be probably needed any additional check - the most important is that the job will start after all records are deleted and thereafter reinserted with new ones